# Retrieving a specific part of a string in R

Tags: r, substring

I have the next vector of strings

```
[1] "/players/playerpage.htm?ilkidn=BRYANPHI01"
[2] "/players/playerpage.htm?ilkidhh=WILLIROB027"
[3] "/players/playerpage.htm?ilkid=THOMPWIL01"
```

I am looking for a way to  retrieve the part of the string that is placed after the equal sign meaning I would like to get a vector like this

```
[1] "BRYANPHI01"
[2] "WILLIROB027"
[3] "THOMPWIL01"
```

I tried using substr but for it to work I have to know exactly where the equal sign is placed in the string and where the part i want to retrieve ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the zero or more characters that are not a `=` (`[^=]*`) followed by a `=` and replace it with `''`.

```
sub("[^=]*=", "", str1)
#[1] "BRYANPHI01"  "WILLIROB027" "THOMPWIL01"
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  c("/players/playerpage.htm?ilkidn=BRYANPHI01",  
          "/players/playerpage.htm?ilkidhh=WILLIROB027",
          "/players/playerpage.htm?ilkid=THOMPWIL01")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `stringr`,

```
library(stringr)
word(str1, 2, sep = '=')
#[1] "BRYANPHI01"  "WILLIROB027" "THOMPWIL01"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `strsplit`,

```
strsplit(str1, "=")[[1]][2]
# [1] "BRYANPHI01"
```

With Sotos comment to get results as vector:

```
sapply(str1, function(x){
  strsplit(x, "=")[[1]][2]
})
```

Comment: if you want the list of only the second parts, yes, editing it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on regex, but extracting instead of substituting, which may be more efficient.

I use the `stringi` package which provides a more powerful regex engine than base R (in particular, supporting look-behind).

```
str1 <-  c("/players/playerpage.htm?ilkidn=BRYANPHI01",  
          "/players/playerpage.htm?ilkidhh=WILLIROB027",
          "/players/playerpage.htm?ilkid=THOMPWIL01")
stri_extract_all_regex(str1, pattern="(?<==).+$", simplify=T)
```

`(?<==)` is a look-behind: regex will match only if preceded by an equal sign, but the equal sign will not be part of the match.

`.+$` matches everything until the end. You could replace the dot with a more precise symbol if you are confident about the format of what you match. For example, '\w' matches any alphanumeric character, so you could use `"(?<==)\\w+$"` (the `\` must be escaped so you end up with `\\w`).